# Cant send discord messages via API

Tags: api, discord, token

I wrote this code in python to send a message = "message" to my own channel (with 3 members). It is supposed to complete it and print "200" as a success, it instead doesn't write "200", it writes "400" and doesn't send anything to the channel.

In this question I removed the channel and the token and wrote "ggbro" instead.

```
import requests
payload ={
        "contant": 'message'
    }
header ={
    "authorization": 'GGBRO'
}

r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/GGBRO/messages',data=payload, headers=header)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: "contant" might be a typo...?

Comment: Should this code be Python or JavaScript? Please remove the tags that do not fit the question. IMHO, discord.js should be removed. Why is your code duplicate? Please post code that is similar to your code. IMHO the first request will throw an exception even before anything is printed.

Comment: HTTP 400 = Bad Request